# how can i send accepted socket to a function as argument

Tags: c++, c, sockets

How can I send accepted socket to a function as argument here is the code:

```
//accept connection 
accept_sock = accept(sock_con,(struct sockaddr *)&info,&sizeof_accept);

//Create a new process
int pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0)
   {

    //close the socket
    close(sock_con);
    request_handle(accept_sock);   ** here i wanna send the socket to that function*
    }
```

What is the datatype of that socket when declaring this function?

```
function request_handle(what is the datatype pointed here){

}
```

Comment: How did you manage to declare `accept_sock` without knowing its type? What did you read in `accept`'s man page?

Comment: He might copied the code and didn't even toke the chance to read it.

Comment: it's just my frst experience of programming , i just try learning by practice

Comment: @kingasmk then tracing is a skill you need to acquire.

Answer (score 1):

accept_sock is an int. See manpage for [accept](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept).

int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

Answer (score 0):

```
function request_handle(int socket);
```

Sockets file descriptors are integers associated with the socket that was opened in the kernel to distinguish between each socket, just like file descriptors are integers to distinguish between opened files and get the appropriate one, some says everything in a Unix is a file, that's because of the integer associated or the file descriptor concept.

Answer (score 0):

The socket is a handle usually an `int` or `unsigned int` (depends on implementation), this will be used by the socket dll to uniquely identify the socket you are referring to when you pass this as an argument to `send` `recv` etc..

So you just need to do this:

```
function request_handle(int socketHandle){

}
```